# Hbase remote connection

Tags: hadoop, hbase, remote-access

I have a Hadoop cluster set up in 7 AWS instances and HBase installed in it. I am trying to manipulate an HBase table from a machine which **is not in the cluster**. Using the HBase API, I have written the following code, which only works if it is executed in one of the cluster nodes:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();

//This reads hdfs-site.xml
HdfsConfiguration hdfsConf = new HdfsConfiguration();

System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", new Path("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client").toString());

//This reads core-site.xml and hbase-site.xml
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, PUBLIC_DNS);

HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);

Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
TableName tName = TableName.valueOf("history_sample");
Table t = conn.getTable(tName);
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("100005379"));
Result res = t.get(get);
byte[] geoloc_date = res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("general_data"), Bytes.toBytes("geoloc_date"));
System.out.println("Example value: " + Bytes.toString(geoloc_date));

t.close();
conn.close();
```

What I am trying to do is to create a similar code which would work on my local machine, which is outside the Hadoop cluster, I don't want to execute the jar file in one of the cluster nodes.